# Generate all possible permutations (or n-tuples)

Tags: r

I'd like to create a data.frame of all possible permutations of 10 variables that can be either 1 or 2

```
2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 1024 # possible

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1
...
```

Is there a "quick" way to do this in R?

Comment: There's a `permutations` function in gregmisc I believe.  You can coerce the resulting matrix to a data.frame.

Comment: Alternatively `combn` in `base`, combined with `unique(x, MARGIN=2)`.

Comment: Not a permutation. [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) are rearrangements of objects. You cannot rearrange `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1` into `1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1`, because the first string does not have any `2`.

Comment: How should the question be edited to avoid calling these “permutations”?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

how about this:

```
tmp = expand.grid(1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2)
```

or this (thanks Tyler):

```
x <- list(1:2)
tmp = expand.grid(rep(x, 10))
```

Comment: To type less code you could use: `x <- list(1:2);` 
`tmp = expand.grid(rep(x, 10))`

Comment: I guess I'm asking too much, but it crashes when you try a large number like: expand.grid(0:451, 0:451, 0:451, 0:451). Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @aguiar what is 452^4? -- that will be the number of combinations. That is almost 10 times the limit the length of a vector on 32-bit R,  so you would need 64 bit R and perhaps 1 terrabyte of Ram!

Answer (score 0):

Some people have asked the question regarding letters, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150234/create-all-possible-permutations-of-two-vectors-in-r). The expand.grid solution is usually given, but I find this to be much simpler:

```
sapply(LETTERS[1:3], function(x){paste0(x, LETTERS[1:3])}) %>% c()
# [1] "AA" "AB" "AC" "BA" "BB" "BC" "CA" "CB" "CC"
```