# create all possible permutations of two vectors in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors like this:

```
f1=c('a','b','c','d')
e1=c('e','f','g')
```

There is 4^3 different permutations of them. I need to create all of possible permutations of them in R softeware.for example;

```
(1):
a e
a f
a g
(2):
a e
a f
b g
...
```

Moreover, my real data are very huge and I need speed codes.

Comment: This is a many times over duplicate and I don't think the search terms are that obtuse. Did you really search before you posted?

Comment: Can't post an answer, but see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56154619/188963) that I think is much better suited to this problem.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you are looking for `expand.grid`.

```
> expand.grid(f1, e1)
   Var1 Var2
1     a    e
2     b    e
3     c    e
4     d    e
5     a    f
6     b    f
7     c    f
8     d    f
9     a    g
10    b    g
11    c    g
12    d    g
```

I don't know what "speed codes" are, so I'm not sure I can help from that aspect.